popen3 not capturing full output
I have a bash script that takes several seconds to finish running. Because of this, popen3 seems to be cutting off the output, simply capturing the beginning echo statements in my bash script. How do I get popen3 to wait and capture the full output of my bash script?
Here is the relevant part of my app.rb:
get '/' do
  script_path = "/path/to/bash/script"
  @output, @error = execute_script(script_path)
  erb :index
end

def execute_script(script, *args)
  command = "#{script} #{args.join(' ')}"
  output = ""
  error = ""

  Open3.popen3(command) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    stdout_thread = Thread.new { output << stdout.read }
    stderr_thread = Thread.new { error << stderr.read }

    stdout_thread.join
    stderr_thread.join

    exit_status = wait_thr.value
    unless exit_status.success?
      error << "\nCommand failed with exit code #{exit_status.exitstatus}"
    end
  end

  return output, error
end

I figured the threads should've helped the program wait for the bash script to finish outputting, but that does not seem to be the case.
Here is the bash script for reference:
#!/bin/bash

MAM_PATH="/opt/mam/current/bin/"

case "$1" in
"")
  line="%-20s %15s %15s %15s %15s\n"
  printf "$line" "Account" "Balance" "Reserved" "Available"
  printf "$line" "-----------------" "---------" "---------" "---------"
  array=()

  for ACCOUNT in $($MAM_PATH/mam-list-accounts -A --quiet --show Name);do 
        read -r Allocated Remaining <<< $($MAM_PATH/mam-list-allocations -a $ACCOUNT -A --quiet --show Allocated,Remaining|awk '{ sum += $1; sum2 += $2 } END { print sum, sum2}')
        Reserved="0"
        if [[ -z $Remaining ]];then 
                Allocated=0;Remaining=0;array+=($ACCOUNT)
        else
                printf "$line" "$ACCOUNT" "$Allocated" "$Reserved" "$Remaining"
        fi
  done

  printf "\n for more information about a specific allocation,\n run: 'allocations -a <allocation name>'\n"
  ;;
-a)
  $MAM_PATH/mam-list-allocations -a $2 --show Description,StartTime,EndTime,Allocated,Remaining,PercentUsed,Active
  printf "\n"
  $MAM_PATH/mam-list-users -a $2 --show Name,Active,CommonName,EmailAddress,DefaultAccount
  printf "PI: $(mam-list-accounts -a $2 --show Users | sed -n '3p'| cut -d '^' -f2 | cut -d ',' -f1)\n"
  ;;
-u)
 echo "FundName      Active Description StartTime           EndTime    Allocated  Remaining"
 echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
 sudo $MAM_PATH/mam-list-allocations -u $2 --quiet --show FundName,Active,Description,StartTime,EndTime,Allocated,Remaining | sort -r | awk '!seen[$1]++'
 ;;
*)
  printf "\n for more information about a specific allocation,\n run: 'allocations -a <allocation name>'\n"
  ;;
esac

Any help is greatly appreciated.

You don't need threads to wait, read already waits for the end of the output. Can you show what's in your bash script?

Thanks, Alex, that's what I thought. I've updated the question with the bash script.

since I can't run mam-list-* scripts, substituting with some echos and sleeps everything prints for me. sudo - potential unhandled password prompt? does the script run with a simple system or if you need to capture the output %x()?

It seems the issue has to do with how our system handles access to that $MAM_PATH directory. Everything else works fine, it's just a permissions issue.
